# How to open a database file start with "DBFL"?

Tags: database, file-format

I got a Nokia backup file (.cdb) - it's kindof database file. The first four bytes of the file are "DBFL".

Is it a well-known database file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's CardScan file. I suggest best way would be to download CardScan softwarte and try export from there to some more reliable format.